# copy layers from one Photoshop document to another with changable size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to copy layers from one Photoshop document to another so that we  can change the size of image in new Photoshop document.

Answer (score 2):

Simply resize document, then save with a different name--if you don't want all the layers--delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: The answer makes sense but the editorial bit at the beginning is not necessary!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select the layers you want to copy. After that you just go to the top menu and select "Layer" > "Duplicate layers..." and than in the "Document" you change the select to "new".

The layers you chose will be in the exact position before.

I should be work.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the size of the "image" which is the whole PS file, or size of the new layer? The first is possible anytime on any Photoshop document. To resize a layer without changing the entire image size (assuming this is what you are asking) do the following:

1. In the source document, target the layer you wish to bring to the other document (destination) and press Ctrl-A, this will select the entire layer content
2. Press Ctrl-C to copy the selection
3. In your destination document, press Ctrl-V to paste the copied content as a layer
4. Press Ctrl-T to activate the Free Transform Tool, you will see a frame around the layer and handles on each corner and the middle of each side. If the destination document is smaller than the source you copied, the transform frame may be outside the visible image. Press Ctrl-0 to fit the entire image to screen to see the handles
5. If you want to maintain the same proportion when you scaled the new layer, hold the Shift key down as you drag one of the corners in or out depending on whether you want to reduce or enlarge the new layer
6. You can position this layer by click-and-drag from its content area, but that can be done any time after the scaling is finished
7. When the new layer is of the size you want, press the ENTER key which will complete the resizing

Repeat for the other layers. If you wish to copy more than one layer and resize them at the same time and to the same size the copy and paste process needs to be done by drag and drop in a particular way. In that case, do the following for steps 1-3 above:

1. Open both your source and destination files
2. In the source document, Click on the first source layer, then Ctrl-Click on the other layers you wish to bring to the destination document
3. While all the layers to be copied are targeted, bring your mouse to the image area, pay particular attention to the drag and drop process below
4. Click and drag from the image content area and bring your mouse over the tab of the destination document but DO NOT DROP the layers you are carrying, hover until the destination document comes forward, now bring your mouse inside the destination image and drop the layers
5. They will be in place altogether and still selected. Make sure to do the step 4 and after while all these layers are selected. Then they will resize the same way.